# Invalid option error using avcodec_open2 and libopus

Tags: ffmpeg, opus

I'm getting an invalid option result from `avcodec_open2` in ffmpeg 3.1.6 with libopus 1.1.4. I've sorted through all the options and I cannot locate the offending option, [I created a gist holding the relevant native code](https://gist.github.com/mondain/acbec32fb1d120b7da1b393bfca8180b). I've searched all about the internet and cannot find anything helpful as of yet. I've also tried with and without the opts dictionary.

```
results = avcodec_open2(context, codec, &opts);
```

and

```
results = avcodec_open2(context, codec, 0);
```

All tests and variations return `-22` (at line 51 in gist)

Answer (score 1):

> `memset(context, 0, sizeof(context));`

That code needs to be removed. It will basically break everything. Specifically, it will unset all things set in `avcodec_alloc_context3()` based on the `codec` parameter, as well as more generally all codec-agnostic defaults.

(Note that it only zeroes the first 8 (on x86-64) bytes, since you used `sizeof(context)` instead of `sizeof(*context)`).

Comment: I have removed the offending line; thank you. However, the code sill doesn't work.

Comment: At that point, your stderr should tell you which priv options are missing when you call avcodec_open2() with a non-NULL opts.